# R vector staying the same length after indexing within recursive function

Tags: r, performance, indexing, binary-search

I wrote a recursive binary search function in R which finds the smallest element in a vector that is greater than a given value:

```
binary_next_biggest <- function(x, vec){
  if (length(vec) == 1){
    if (x < vec[1]){
      return(vec[1])
    } else {
      return(NA)
    }
  } else {
    mid = ceiling(length(vec)/2)
    if (x < vec[mid]){
      return(binary_next_biggest(x, vec[1:mid]))
    } else {
      return(binary_next_biggest(x, vec[mid+1:length(vec)]))
    }
  }
}
```

I've written this exact same function in Python with no issues (code below), but in R it does not work.

```
import numpy as np

def binary_next_biggest(x, arr):
    if len(arr)==1:
        if x < arr[0]:
            return arr[0]
        else:
            return None
    else:
        mid = int(np.ceil(len(arr)/2)-1)
        if x < arr[mid]:
            return binary_next_biggest(x, arr[:mid+1])
        else:
            return binary_next_biggest(x, arr[mid+1:])
```

Through debugging in RStudio I discovered the mechanics of why it's not working: indexing the vector in my above function is returning a vector of the same length, so that if

```
vec <- 1:10
```

and vec is indexed within the function,

```
vec[6:10]
```

the resulting vector passed to the new call of binary_next_biggest() is

```
6 7 8 9 10 NA NA NA NA NA
```

where I would expect

```
6 7 8 9 10
```

What's going on here? I know I can just rewrite it as a while loop iteratively changing indexes, but I don't understand why vector indexing is behaving this way in the code I've written. Within the interactive R console indexing behaves as expected and changes the vector length, so why would it behave differently within a function, and what would be the appropriate way to index for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Try `(mid+1):length(vec)` instead of `mid+1:length(vec)`.

Comment: Ah, that did it. Now I feel dumb lol, that's gotten me before. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyShabalin Do you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can select it and close the question?

Comment: Sure, will post an an answer.

Comment: Depends on whether your data is integer or float, I guess, but `findInterval(vs, DF$v)` or `findInterval(vs, DF$v) + 1L` should work to find the position of the match; then just `DF$v[res]` on that for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the strange behavior of the code is an error in indexing of the vector elements. The part `mid+1:length(vec)` should be `(mid+1):length(vec)` because the `:` operator is executed before addition.

Here is an illustration of the difference.

```
5 + 1:10
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
(5+1):10
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a reason why you're doing a binary search (simplified example of more complicated problem?), but there are easier ways to do this in R.

```
vec <- 1:1000
x <- 49
min(vec[which(vec > x)])
# [1] 50
```

Which works even if vec isn't ordered.

```
vec <- sample.int(1000)
min(vec[which(vec > x)])
# [1] 50
```

Comment: Yep, I have a big sorted data.frame on which I will have to perform the search millions of times, so I wouldn't expect which to be efficient enough for my case. Thanks though!

Comment: Might be worth asking with an example closer to what you're trying to do. I can't imagine running the recursive function millions of times will be quick.